# Javascript Replace Child/Loop issue

Tags: javascript, for-loop, parent-child

I have this really bizarre issue where I have a forloop that is supposed to replace all divs with the class of "original" to text inputs with a class of "new". When I run the loop, it only replaces every-other div with an input, but if I run the loop to just replace the class of the div and not change the tag to input, it does every single div, and doesn't only do every-other.

Here is my loop code, and a link to the live version: [live version here](http://r3dux.com/css/div.html)

```
function divChange()    {
    var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    for (var i=0; i<divs.length; i++) {
        if (divs[i].className == 'original') {
            var textInput = document.createElement('input');
            textInput.className = 'new';
            textInput.type = 'text';
            textInput.value = divs[i].innerHTML;
            var parent = divs[i].parentNode;
            parent.replaceChild(textInput, divs[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Iterate in reverse instead of forward. When you remove the `div`, it also gets removed from the `divs` collection, so you end up skipping indices.

Comment: ah, so have var i = divs.length; i>0; i--?

Comment: Yes, almost. `var i = divs.length - 1; i > -1; i--`

Comment: ah, brilliant. too bad you didn't post this as an answer. lol

Comment: @user1689607 Or `for ( var i = divs.length - 1; i--; )...`

Comment: @David: That's another good way. :)

Comment: @David There's no condition in that loop.

Comment: Yeah, wouldn't @David's loop run forever?

Comment: @Asad, Charles: `i` will eventually be `0`, which is falsey, so the condition fails and the loop halts at that point.

Comment: @Asad Not really -- http://jsfiddle.net/CrJDm/

Comment: @CharlesJohnThompsonIII: I posted my comments as an answer.

Comment: lol, apparently the question has to be up for a set amount of time before I can accept an answer.

Comment: @Neil, I have gone over my old questions, there is a reason I didn't accept the answer, that being it wasn't valid for my question/purpose. but thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the `divs` collection is updated when one of its `div` elements is removed from the DOM, you end up skipping over divs because your `i` isn't updated with the reindexing of the collection.

A common solution is to iterate in reverse instead.

```
function divChange()    {
    var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    for (var i=divs.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
        if (divs[i].className == 'original') {
            var textInput = document.createElement('input');
            textInput.className = 'new';
            textInput.type = 'text';
            textInput.value = divs[i].innerHTML;
            divs[i].parentNode.replaceChild(textInput, divs[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution you could use is to copy the live HTMLCollection to an inert array, and use your original logic:

```
function divChange() {
    var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    divs = Array.prototype.slice.call( divs ); //convert to array
    for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        if (divs[i].className == 'original') {
            var textInput = document.createElement('input');
            textInput.className = 'new';
            textInput.type = 'text';
            textInput.value = divs[i].innerHTML;
            var parent = divs[i].parentNode;
            parent.replaceChild(textInput, divs[i]);
        }
    }
}

divChange();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2UCZa/1/

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution is to create an Array from an array-like object, and iterate over this. For example:

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");

Array.from(divs).forEach(function(el) {
  if (el.className == 'original') {
        var textInput = document.createElement('input');
        textInput.className = 'new';
        textInput.type = 'text';
        textInput.value = el.innerHTML;
        var parent = el.parentNode;
        parent.replaceChild(textInput, el);
    }
});
```

I like this one the best, as it produces the least amount of code, and is very clear!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but this one seemed to work in the end:

```
ModalBody.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', loader.outerHTML);
```

my loader is basically just a new div, but inside of the div there is this loading symbol, which appears when the content is loaded.

```
var loader = document.createElement('div');
loader.classList.add('loader');
loader.classList.add('is-loading');
loader.classList.add('mt-5');
```

So with just this line

```
ModalBody.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', loader);
```

...while the content was loaded a got [object HTMLDivElement] shown shortly, after 3 sec more or less the right content appeared. As soon as I added this ".outerHTML" things got right. I am still a super beginner. So, maybe someone could also explaine why this worked?